# multiple chunk from .wav file with specific timeframe

Tags: node.js, audio, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg, nodejs-stream

I want to create multiple `.mp4` files from `.wav` audio file for specific given time.

#### Input:

`.wav` audio file with length of **120 sec.**

- chunks timeframes are

  1. start: 20s, end: 35sec
  2. start: 45s, end: 105sec
  3. ...

#### Output:

- Output would be two .mp4 audio file
- Audio file with length of 15sec  (20s - 35s)
- Audio file with length of 20sec  (45s - 105s)
- ...

I'm using [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) lib for that, How can I do that?

Comment: Cmd would be `ffmpeg -i in.wav -ss 20 -t 15 one.mp4 -ss 45 -t 60 two.mp4`

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya
I did the same but when I'm playing the audio in VLC, the timeline not progressing with the audio. means we can't show how much seconds passed.

Comment: Share the console output for the command.